# could not change directory to "/home/corey/scripts": Permission denied

Tags: bash, shell-script

I get the error message...

```
could not change directory to "/home/corey/scripts": Permission denied
```

... when I run the following script ...

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u postgres psql < setup_dev_db.sql
read -rsp $'Press any key to continue...\n' -n 1 key
```

... the contents of setup_dev_db.sql are executed without any issues, but the error is annoying.

Can I get rid of it?

Comment: Let's try to localize where the error is. If you type `sudo -u postgres`, do you get the same error?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick is on the right track. There are too many things going on with your script to easily identify WHICH is causing the problem. However, the quick check would be to review permissions for user **postgres** on the folder **/home/corey/scripts**

Comment: I suspect it's simply because the OP ran the script from that directory, which the `postgres` user can't read, and the error would go away if the script was run from, say, `/tmp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: There is [discussion about this issue](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/797232.1662075573@sss.pgh.pa.us) in Postgres mailing list and it [has been fixed in PostgreSQL 16](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/11a0a8b529caeab101206ec4a33af95bb4445746).

**Reason for the error**:
While [@lambart's solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396433/348690) are correct, the reason for the error is not since it has nothing to do with `.psql_history` file. The

```bash
could not change directory to "/home/corey/scripts": Permission denied
```

error is coming from [`resolve_symlinks()` function](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/496a1dc44bf1261053da9b3f7e430769754298b4/src/common/exec.c#L318-L323) which resolves symlinks using `chdir` and finally tries to `chdir` back to the original directory which fails if the user executing `psql` does not have permissions to do so. The `resolve_symlinks()` call comes from `find_my_exec()` which in turn is called by [`set_pglocale_pgservice()`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/fc2d260c7e6236fe2447dad0f8415e72f4be66a2/src/common/exec.c#L448) (which sets `PGSYSCONFDIR` and `PGLOCALEDIR`).

**Solutions for older versions**:

For versions prior 16, the error is fixed by giving the user executing `psql` command `x` permission to the working directory where the command is issued. This can be done in several ways:

1. Add `-i` to `sudo` command to use login shell which changes the working directory to the home directory of the postgres user before executing the  `psql` command (postgres user naturally has the `x` permission to its own home directory):

   ```bash
   sudo -i -u postgres psql < setup_dev_db.sql
   ```
2. Give postgres user `x` permission to the current working directory by adding it to the group owning the working directory:

   ```bash
   # Get group owning the current directory
   stat -c "%G" .
   # Add postgres user to that group
   sudo usermod -aG <group above here> postgres
   ```
3. Give postgres user `x` permission to the current working directory by giving `x` permission to "others" to the working directory. This can be handy e.g., in single user VM-based systems meant for development, such as WSL2 where simple `chmod o+x /home/$USER` command will fix the error.
4. Run the `psql` using current user which of course have permissions to the current working directory.
5. Before executing the command, change working directory to a directory where postgres user has `x` permission, e.g., `cd /tmp`.

Answer (score 10):

Postgres wants to create a `$HOME/.psql_history` file, where it will store all your queries and commands from the `psql` client. It may well want to do something else at `$HOME`, but I don't see any evidence in the form of other hidden files. And it won't actually create the history file unless you're using `psql` interactively, which you're not.

I had this exact same problem and found this question, but the accepted answer wasn't acceptable to me -- I shouldn't have to grant postgres permission to leave a trail of my queries in whatever directory I happen to be in when I run a script!

@Corey, the solution you mentioned in your comment (`cd /tmp` before calling `sudo...`) is probably the best. `psql` won't create this file in `/tmp` (I'm sure that's deliberate, because it could allow unprivileged users to read the file).

There are two other solutions I can think of :

1. Run `psql` in a login shell by adding `-i` to your command

   ```
   sudo -i -u postgres psql < setup_dev_db.sql
   ```

   This will set `$HOME` to `postgres`'s `HOME` directory, listed in `/etc/passwd`. For Ubuntu, that's `/var/lib/postgres`. But since you're piping in commands, it won't create a `.psql_history` file. However, if you use interactive `psql`, anyone else with `sudo` privileges on the machine *will* have access to your command history.

   I'm not sure if there are any other negative consequences to running a login shell in this situation.
2. Run `psql` as a less-privileged user, e.g.

   ```
   $ psql dev_db -hlocalhost corey_dev -W < setup_dev_db.sql
   ```

   If this is a problem because you leave postgres user creation to your `setup_dev_db.sql` script, and you don't have any users yet, just add a `createuser` command in your script first, something like this:

   ```
   $ sudo -u postgres createuser corey_dev -P
   ```

   and perhaps ...

   ```
   $ sudo -u postgres createdb dev_db "Dev database"
   ```

**NOTE: When using the `psql` client interactively** (which you're not, here), if you see a message like `could not change directory to "/home/corey/scripts": Permission denied` message ****, `psql` **is** going to write to `/var/lib/postgres/.psql_history` (or wherever its `$HOME` is)! If you've ever seen that warning when using interactive `psql`, go look--you'll probably find a hidden history file.

Comment: I had to do `sudo -u postgres -i psql -U .... ` because `sudo -u -i postgres psql -U ` and `sudo -ui postgres psql -U ...` didn't work.

Comment: I don't think that `psql` wanting to write to `$HOME/.psql_history` is the cause of this issue.  In support of this suspicion I would like to offer the output of `sudo -u postgres bash -c 'echo $HOME'`, which is `/var/lib/postgresql`; so writing to `.psql_history` should just work.  No, for some reason,`psql` seems to insist on doing a `chdir` first to whatever the current working directory is, which for a non`-i`nteractive `sudo` will be the working directory of the invoker; hence the _"could not change directory to `/home/corey/scripts`"_ output, which is unlikely to be someone's homedir.

Comment: However, if you _do_ see your own homedirectory printed, then adding a `--set-home` flag to `sudo` will definitely print the homedir of the `postgres` user;  but I will bet that, all other things considered equal, `sudo --set-home -u postgres psql` will _still_ print the _"could not change directory to ..."_ error.

Answer (score 7):

To change to a directory, a user must have the 'x' permission for that directory.

I assume you are running the script from '/home/corey/scripts'. When 'sudo -u postgres' changes the current user to 'postgres' it attempts to set the working directory for 'postgres' to the working directory it was called from generating the error you're seeing.

Make sure that the user 'postgres' has permission 'x' for '/home/corey/scripts'.

Comment: I added "cd /tmp" to the top of my file and prefixed "setup_dev_db.sql" with "~/Dropbox/scripts/" and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `sudo -u postgres -c your_command.bash` or `su postgres -c your_command.bash`.
You could also use,

```
su - postgres your_command.bash
```

This will ensure that you acquired all the postgres account enviroment.

Comment: won't work if you don't want _everything_ in the script to run as root...

Answer (score 0):

For me this did the trick, pay attention to quotes (')

```
sudo -Hiu postgres 'pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only --table=someTable entities_db > /var/backups/anywhere/$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_someTable.sql'
```

Note the `-Hiu`for sudo, or use `su - postgres`

you can also put that in a cronjob for root with `crontab -e`